# Dark Souls 2 - Increase Melee Damage

Tags: dark-souls-2

Just a simple question here. I just watched a SL1 on NG+ kill Fume Knight hitting for 500dmg with a rapier and gold pine resin. I also watched another player with 40str/40dex and a twin blade with gold pine resin hit Fume Knight for roughly 600 per.

My SL is 130, I'm pure melee with 30str/30dex, I use a +10 rapier or estoc with gold pine resin and I hit for 130ish...

What am I possibly doing wrong? How is it even possible to achieve such high dmg on SL1?

I'd like to start bumping up the game level.. but my dmg is just terrible for reasons unknown to me.

Comment: Have a relevant link to said sl1 killing fume knight?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQS4DI5O1Zw      It's on the wiki page for Fume Knight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guy in the video is using the [Brightbug](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Brightbug), the effects are:

- Almost if not doubles attack and splits damage received to about half.
- The duration of the effect is 120 seconds, not affected by the Lingering Dragoncrest Ring.
- Does not stack with other self buffs.

He may also be using a [Ring of Blades](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ring+of+Blades), the [Lightning Clutch Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Lightning+Clutch+Ring), and the [Old Leo Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Old+Leo+Ring). I'm not familiar with the gear he's wearing but I presume there is a reason he is wearing it. Hope that helped!

**EDIT:**

He is using these items:

- [Flower Skirt +10](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Flower+Skirt) (+2 VGR, +1 END)
- [Crown of the Sunken King +5](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Crown+of+the+Sunken+King+Helm) (-1 VGR, -1 VIT, +1 STR, +1 DEX, +1 INT, +1 END, and +1 FTH)
- [Raw Rapier +10](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Rapier) (highest base damage because scaling is insignificant at sl1)
- [Ring of Blades +2](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Ring+of+Blades) (+50 Physical Attack)
- [Dexterity Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Dexterity+Ring) (+5 Dex)
- [Flynn's Ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Flynn%27s+Ring) (Grants the user bonus physical attack based on their maximum Equip Load stat)
- [Third dragon ring](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Third+Dragon+Ring) (HP, Stam & Load increase)

Comment: I was under the impression the Brightbugs effect only happened if you were near death?

Comment: It looks like what they mean is that people only use it when close to death. The wording is rather unclear though. Give me a second to update the answers, I just got the specifics of his build xD

Comment: Hah. Thanks for all your digging!! Info is appreciated.